# Using audiere library with C

Tags: c, audio, header

Can I use [audiere](http://audiere.sourceforge.net/) in C, the man page doesn't mention that afresh.. and the main header file has "vector" included, which is certainly not a standard C lib.

---

How can I go?

Answer (score 1):

You can't ...

Judging by these lines in `audiere.h`:

```
#ifndef __cplusplus
  #error Audiere requires C++
#endif
```

You're supposed to use `C++`. Its whole API uses `C++` anyway.

Comment: That's awful. I even installed the library for use with C++ but it doesn't work with mingw's g++ .. it gives undefined reference even though I `-I`d all the includes and linked the lib.....